# Product of RREF versus RREF of product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices of arbitrary shape where the number of columns of $A$ is the same as the number of rows of $B$.

Is it always true that

> $$\textbf{rref}[A]\cdot \textbf{rref}[B] = \textbf{rref}[AB]$$

and if it is not true all the time, what conditions guarantee that it will be?

I came across this as a claim by a student while grading and am unable to think of an appropriate proof or counterexample.

In the case that $\ker(A)=\{0\}$ and $\ker(B)=\{0\}$, it will be true that $\ker(AB)=\{0\}$.  This would imply that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent as well as the same for columns of $B$ and $AB$.  This would imply that it each individually rowreduces to an identity above some number of zero-rows and the identity should hold, but what of other cases where a kernel is nontrivial?

Comment: +1)  Ok, RREF essentially is a multi step row operations (of course you already knew that). But the point that came into my mind is the following: If I add row 1 to row 2 in matrix A as well as B and I multiply, do I get the same thing as if I first multiply A and B and then perform that row operation? If so, then that confirms your conjecture. But the case of "one row operation" may be easier to prove (hopefully). Just a thought....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this for a counterexample:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad AB = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Then
$$rref[A] = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad rref[B] = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
so
$$rref[A] \cdot rref[B] = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \neq rref[AB] = AB$$

Comment: +1) That makes my earlier comment redundant... How about though if the matrices are both invertible??

Comment: If the matrices are both invertible then it is true (as proved in my original post) since it is a special case of having trivial kernel.  (Invertible matrices are matrices with trivial kernel AND are square)